# htaccess multi langages 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a website in french and english and I have also a .htaccess.
I would like to do something like this:

```
If the URL has "fr" => Redirection 404 to /vues/404.php?lang=fr
If the URL has "en" => Redirection 404 to /vues/404.php?lang=en
```

Can someone help me please?
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/
ErrorDocument 404   http://localhost:8888/netpom/vues/404.php?lang=fr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fr/
ErrorDocument 404   http://localhost:8888/netpom/vues/404.php?lang=en
```

Answer (score 0):

`ErrorDocument` is a completely different module and not affected by rewrite conditions. You *may* be able to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?:^|/)(en\fr)(?:/|$) /vues/404.php?lang=$1 [L,R=404]
```

Will probably want to put this after most of your other rules if you have any. If the 404 is generated by some sort of framework or content manager, then you can do it this way. You'll need to go through your CMS/framework for that.